# web-based video performance on Intel Atom

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

I'm looking for a web based solution to display HD web based video on cheap hardware.

Looking at some existing HTML5 video solutions I found out that the Rasberry PI is not a good hardware fit, for the reasons explained here:
https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js/wiki/Limitations-(Read-this-for-Android-%7C-Raspberry-Pi-%7C-performance-issues)

Does anyone have information about the performance of Video.js or some other HTML5 video solution on Atom Intel hardware?

Comment: The argument of Raspberry Pi being not a good fit is only relevant to Chimera, I think that using the OMX decoding facilities directly (pushing the video stream to GPU on doing the decoding there) should suffice, the question is if the Raspberry Pi browser does that, but you can trivially check that out by opening some HTML5 videos in Raspbian.

Comment: Some other solutions still possible, but it depends from your requirements. For example you could render video some way which supports hardware acceleration and place HTML contents just over rendered video. I've used this technique in https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera-desktop, and got acceptable (from my point of view) results.

Comment: And  you should look at this: http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.ru/2016/07/binaries-for-pot-540-beta1-on-qt-570.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. My requirement is that I have both video content as well as html content (think digital signage screens) that I need to display either simultaneously or sequentially but in a way that appears to be seamless to the user. @RSATom I did see your solution on github but I'm afraid that by using QML I would not be able to truly leverage the existing HTML5/JS ecosystem (Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with QML)